# Polly Policy.TimeoutAsync not giving TimeoutRejected exception

Tags: c#, timeout, dotnet-httpclient, polly

Here is my sample code:

```cs
var timeoutPolicy = Policy.TimeoutAsync(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(_configOptions.ResponseTimeout), TimeoutStrategy.Pessimistic);
            
try
{
    return await timeoutPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async ct => await Somemethod(request, ct), CancellationToken.None);
}
catch (TimeoutRejectedException ex)
{
    _//Some logging to go here/
}
```

`configOptions.ResponseTimeout` is configured in config file, I am expecting the method `await Somemethod(request, ct)`, `CancellationToken.None` should throw `TimeoutRejectedException` based on the value given in config.

But it is not throwing any exception.
Can anyone please help me to identify where I am going wrong?

Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of the `_configOptions.ResponseTimeout`?

Answer (score 2):

### Optimistic timeout

The delegate **does** support cancellation.

#### The to be executed delegate

```cs
private static async Task SomeMethodAsync(CancellationToken ct = default)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(SomeMethodAsync)} has been called.");
    await Task.Delay(15000, ct); //It is aware of the CancellationToken
}
```

#### The timeout policy

```cs
 private static AsyncTimeoutPolicy GetTimeoutPolicy
    => Policy
        .TimeoutAsync(
            TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000),
            TimeoutStrategy.Optimistic,
            (context, timeout, _, exception) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{"Timeout",-10}{timeout,-10:ss\\.fff}: {exception.GetType().Name}");
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            });
```

#### The usage

```cs
var strategy = GetTimeoutPolicy;
var result = await strategy.ExecuteAsync(async (ct) => await SomeMethodAsync(ct), CancellationToken.None);
```

#### The output

```
SomeMethodAsync has been called.
Timeout   01.000    : TaskCanceledException
Unhandled exception. Polly.Timeout.TimeoutRejectedException: The delegate executed asynchronously through TimeoutPolicy did not complete within the timeout.
 ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
...
```

### Pessimistic timeout

The delegate does **not** support cancellation.

#### The to be executed delegate

```cs
private static async Task SomeMethodAsync(CancellationToken ct = default)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(SomeMethodAsync)} has been called.");
    await Task.Delay(15000); //It is NOT aware of the CancellationToken
}
```

#### The timeout policy

```cs
 private static AsyncTimeoutPolicy GetTimeoutPolicy
    => Policy
        .TimeoutAsync(
            TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000),
            TimeoutStrategy.Pessimistic,
            (context, timeout, _, exception) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{"Timeout",-10}{timeout,-10:ss\\.fff}: {exception.GetType().Name}");
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            });
```

#### The usage

```cs
var strategy = GetTimeoutPolicy;
var result = await strategy.ExecuteAsync(async () => await SomeMethodAsync());
```

#### The output

```
SomeMethodAsync has been called.
Timeout   01.000    : TaskCanceledException
Unhandled exception. Polly.Timeout.TimeoutRejectedException: The delegate executed asynchronously through TimeoutPolicy did not complete within the timeout.
 ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
...
```

Comment: Hi Peter, is it necessary to use await Task.Delay(15000),

Comment: Hi Peter, is it necessary to use await Task.Delay(15000)?,SomeMethodAsync() is calling another async method which should actually give timeout(because it's third party service),using await Task.Delay(15000) is like forcing the method to timeout in specified milliseconds. Correct me if i am wrong?

Comment: @Anonymous No, obviously not. It is just a simulation of an async call. Call whatever method you like there. But please keep in mind that in case of optimistic timeout handling the `cancellationToken` should be passed all the way down.

Comment: I am using pessimistic strategy.

Comment: In case of pessimistic you don't have to pass the cancellation token to the lower layer.

Comment: After removing cancellation token from the calling method, it is still not throwing timeout exception. Also, i can't use await Task.Delay(1000) as it is simulation.i want my calling method to throw timeout exception as per time specified in TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000). Where am i going wrong?

Comment: thanks for your help.using await Task.Delay(1000) works, but i can't use it in my real code. Please suggest what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Please amend your question to reflect to the current state. Please also include the Somemethod body as well.

Comment: Please **amend your question** and do not post code as comment.

Comment: @Anonymous Could you please extend your original question to share with us your updated code to be able to help you with that?